# How to convert custom Mongo DB update query to Java code

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I was finding on the internet how to update all the document field values with lowercase.
I luckily found a query which I modified as per my requirement and it is working correctly.

```
db.messages.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      recipientEmail: {
        $toLower: '$recipientEmail'
      },
      senderEmail: {
        $toLower: '$senderEmail'
      }
    }
  }
],{ multi: true })
```

But now I am trying to convert this query into Java code, I am not able to convert it.
I again started looking into the internet, but couldn’t find any code.
So, can anyone help me convert this query to Java code so that I can use it in my Spring Boot application?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Query annotation in your repository interface and pass your query as it is (above the method signature).
Here is an example :

```java
@Query("{$and:["
            + "     {'id': ?0},"
            + "     {$or:["
            + "         {'customerId': ?1},"
            + "         {'specificCode': ?4}"
            + "     ]},"
            + "     {'beginDate' : { $gte: ?2}},"
            + "     {$or:["
            + "             {'endDate' : { $lte: ?2}},"
            + "             {'endDate' : {$exists: false}}"
        
            + "     ]},"
            + "     {'numberOfTimesUsed': { $lt: ?3}}"
            + "]}")
```

Comment: I have update query.

Comment: I use mongoTemplate, so is there any way to use mongotemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Query query = new Query();
Update update = new Update();
update.set("recipientEmail", StringOperators.valueOf("recipientEmail").toUpper());
update.set("senderEmail", StringOperators.valueOf("senderEmail").toUpper());
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Messages.class);
```

Since you are aggregation pipeline form of update, you can try this:

```
Query query = new Query();
AggregationUpdate update = AggregationUpdate.update().set("recipientEmail").toValue(StringOperators.valueOf("recipientEmail").toUpper()).set("senderEmail").toValue(StringOperators.valueOf("senderEmail").toUpper());
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Messages.class);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't worked.

Comment: Did it give an error?

Comment: no, but I don't see any update in the documents.

Comment: this is my code.                                                                                                        public void patchVersion11() {
    Query query = new Query();
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("recipientEmail", StringOperators.valueOf("recipientEmail").toLower());
    update.set("senderEmail", StringOperators.valueOf("senderEmail").toLower());
    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Message.class);
    updateSchemaVersion(VERSION_11);
  }

Comment: Try simply querying the database, without update to see, if empty query object, is fetching the documents or not.

Comment: This is the query that I see in debug mode.   { "$set" : { "recipientEmail" : { "$java" : org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.StringOperators$ToLower@2cb03ccc }, "senderEmail" : { "$java" : org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.StringOperators$ToLower@659cb7aa } } }

Comment: This query I see in the console.

Comment: Calling update using query: {} and update: { "$set" : { "recipientEmail" : { "value" : { "raw" : "recipientEmail", "name" : "recipientEmail", "_class" : "org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Fields$AggregationField"}, "_class" : "org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.StringOperators$ToLower"}, "senderEmail" : { "value" : { "raw" : "senderEmail", "name" : "senderEmail", "_class" : "org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Fields$AggregationField"}, "_class" : "org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.StringOperators$ToLower"}}} in collection: messages

Comment: Ok, then this is the issue, most probably`StringOperators.valueOf("senderEmail").toUpper()`

Comment: Let me debug it

Comment: Can u tell me which version of mongodb is requried, as I am getting an compile error for AggregationUpdate.

Comment: Spring data mongodb 3.4.2

Comment: we use api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive:2.7.1")

Comment: ok, then you will not be able to do this. lwer version of spring data doesn't have the support for update via aggregation pipeline